# How to pass values from one class's method to another class's method in Typescript?

Tags: oop, angular, typescript

I'm new to Object Oriented programming and am assuming this should be an easy concept for the seasoned OO programmers, but I'm certainly struggling with it.

In my Angular2 app I have a HttpService class as shown below:

**http.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    addLeaf(parentId, label, name){  
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/addleaf/', 
        {'parentId':parentId,'label':label, 'name':name},
        { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res).subscribe();          
}
```

I try to call this method from within another class as below:

**leaf.ts**

```js
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

export class Leaf{
name: string;
...
http: Http;  // very unsure about these two lines
private httpService: HttpService = new HttpService(this.http)
constructor(input){
    this.name = input.name;
...
add(){
    //what should go here?
    this.httpservice.addLeaf(this.id, this.label, this.name); 
    //error -> cannot read property 'post' of undefined
}
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557365/typescript-calling-a-method-of-another-class), I tried creating an instance of the HttpService class but I get the error that the post function does not exist. Also no luck putting the httpService in the constructor.

I call the method in my html like this:

```
(click)="leaf.add()"
```

**EDIT**: following @peeskillet's answer I modified leaf.ts and added leaf.component.ts as shown:

**leaf.ts**

```js
export class Leaf{
    name: string;
    ...
    constructor(input){
        this.name = input.name;
        ...
    add(){
        //what should go here?
    }
}
```

**leaf.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    providers: [HttpService], 
})

export class LeafComponent {
    leaf: Leaf;
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
        this.httpService.addLeaf(this.leaf.id, this.leaf.type, this.leaf.name) 
    }
}
```

service works fine if I write pre-defined strings in place of the params, but still not sure how I can pass the parameters of the clicked leaf to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular, we use [dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) and [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). What this means is that we do not create the service ourselves, but let Angular create it. Then we just *ask* for the service, then Angular will resolve any dependencies that service has. Take for example

```
@Injectable()
class Service {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

Here, `Service` has a dependency in `Http`. `Http` is not something that we can just grab out of thin air. We can't just do

```
let service = new Service(new Http());
```

`Http` is also dependent on some other services. Here what its constructor looks like

```
class Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, options: RequestOptions) {} 
}
```

You might think that maybe you can just instantiate it with the `ConnectionBackend` and `RequestOptions`

```
new Http(new ConnectionBackend(), new RequestOptions())`
```

But you can't do this either, as `ConnectionBackend` also has required dependencies. It's for this reason that we use Inversion of Control. We just add the service to a container, and when ask for the service, Angular look look up service, as see that it requires, `Http`, and see that `Http` requires `ConnectionBackend` and `RequestOptions`, etc, and Angular will create all the items, looking in its registry for all those items and putting them all together like [Voltron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltron). Then it will give us the service, fully populated.

So add our service to the container, we first need to add the `Injectable` decorator on the service

```
@Injectable()
class Service {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
```

Then we need to add it to the `@NgModule.providers`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpModule ],
  providers: [ Service ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Now, whenever we ask for `Service`, it will be fully populated with the `Http` (which is in the `HttpModule`).

How we ask for the service is through the constructor of either another service or component (directive, pipe, etc)

```
@Component({
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
```

By seeing the `Service` type as a constructor argument, Angular knows to look up the `Service` in its container, then pass it through to us. This is the basics of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control.

In your case of `Leaf`. If is is meant to be a service, then you can do the same

```
@Injectable()
class Leaf {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpModule ],
  providers: [ Leaf, Service ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

If you don't want to add `Leaf` as a provider, you don't need to. Just do

```
@Component({})
class MyComponent {
  leaf: Leaf;

  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.leaf = new Leaf(service);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation on the service, but I'm still unclear on how to pass parameters to methods of that service. Leaf in my case is an object that has a few properties (name, label, etc) and I would like to pass those values to my http service.

Comment: I don't think the service should be a member of the leaf. I think you should just have the both the leaf and service members of the component. Then when you want to send the request, just get the properties from the leaf and pass it to the service method.

Comment: yes, I removed the service from leaf and made a new component, added the service there and if I put pre-defined strings in the place of the parameters, the service works fine, but I still don't know how to hook my parameters from when I click on a leaf object to that service. I will edit the question to elaborate.

Comment: Why don't you pass a `Leaf` to `httpService.addLeaf(leaf)`. Or I don't see why it is so difficult to just pass whatever required parameters to the service method. What problems are you actually having with this. Looks pretty straight forward to me. Where are the `parentId, label, name` supposed to come from?

Comment: yes, that is my problem. the parentId, label, and name come from an instance of leaf that I click on. So my issue is: what method should be called onclick? I am assuming it should be a method that I defined on the Leaf class. If yes, then how is that method calling the httpService

Comment: Why not just call a method in the component. In the component method you can do all your required activity with the leaf and service

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that while capturing the parameters. For instance when I do leaf.add() if add is defined in the Leaf class I understand how to access params there but when I'm in another component, I'm not even clear how I can call a method onclick on the object that does not have that method as one of its members(I get the error -> self.parent.context.add is not a function)

Comment: I don't understand. What other component are you talking about? And how is the leaf in _this_ component, related to _that_ component. If we're talking about the same component here, why don't you just add the method `addLeaf` in the component. That will be the onClick callback. Other than that, I'm not quite sure I really understand the problem

Comment: Solved the problem by 1- adding the method on the same component and 2-passing the object to the method as opposed to running the method on the object. Basically add(leaf), instead of leaf.add(). Figured it out thanks to you.